# Как изменить размер одного из нескольких path внутри тега

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg, svg-animation

У меня есть иконка `Facebook` ниже её SVG код

```html
<svg version="1.1" height="40px" width="40px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 291.319 291.319" style="enable-background:new 0 0 291.319 291.319;" xml:space="preserve">
                <g>
                    <path style="fill:#3B5998;" d="M145.659,0c80.45,0,145.66,65.219,145.66,145.66c0,80.45-65.21,145.659-145.66,145.659
              S0,226.109,0,145.66C0,65.219,65.21,0,145.659,0z" />
                    <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M163.394,100.277h18.772v-27.73h-22.067v0.1c-26.738,0.947-32.218,15.977-32.701,31.763h-0.055
              v13.847h-18.207v27.156h18.207v72.793h27.439v-72.793h22.477l4.342-27.156h-26.81v-8.366
              C154.791,104.556,158.341,100.277,163.394,100.277z" />
                </g>
            </svg>
```

Логотип `f` находится внутри круга, и я хочу сделать его меньше. Я пытаюсь понять, как это сделать, но безуспешно. Получается только уменьшить иконку в целом.

У меня есть несколько таких SVG-иконок, у которых мне нужно выборочно уменьшить только внутренние элементы. 
При уменьшении одного `path` (символ `f`) он смещается влево и вверх относительно внешнего круга.
Как  сделать уменьшение `f` по центру внешнего круга?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/59046502/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы символ `f` не смещался при изменении его размера, необходимо использовать правило CSS [transform-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box) : fill-box

> The transform-box CSS property defines the layout box to which the
>   transform and transform-origin properties relate.

**Это правило очень полезно, так как избавляет от поиска и указания центра  трансформируемой фигуры, как при `scale` так и при других трансформациях, например: вращения.**

Найдите в SVG иконке `Facebook` фрагмент кода, который отвечает за вывод символа `F` 
Присвойте ему класс и используйте правило CSS `transform-box:fill-box;`

Ниже в коде размер символа `f` уменьшен на 20%

```css
.facebook {
transform-box: fill-box;
transform-origin: center center;
transform: scale(0.8); 
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" height="40px" width="40px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 291.319 291.319" style="enable-background:new 0 0 291.319 291.319;" xml:space="preserve">
            <g>
                <path style="fill:#3B5998;" d="M145.659,0c80.45,0,145.66,65.219,145.66,145.66c0,80.45-65.21,145.659-145.66,145.659
          S0,226.109,0,145.66C0,65.219,65.21,0,145.659,0z" />
             </g> 
  <g>   
    <path class="facebook" style="fill:#fff;" d="M163.394,100.277h18.772v-27.73h-22.067v0.1c-26.738,0.947-32.218,15.977-32.701,31.763h-0.055
          v13.847h-18.207v27.156h18.207v72.793h27.439v-72.793h22.477l4.342-27.156h-26.81v-8.366
          C154.791,104.556,158.341,100.277,163.394,100.277z" />
            </g>
        </svg>
```

Чтобы показать, что символ `f` не теряет центральной позиции при уменьшении, увеличении размера, запустите код:

### анимация JS + SVG

```js
var svg1 = document.getElementById("svg1"),
  scale = document.getElementById('an_scale'),
  reduce = document.getElementById('an_reduce');
  
 svg1.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
   scale.beginElement();
}); 

   svg1.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
   reduce.beginElement();
});
```

```css
.facebook {
transform-box: fill-box;
transform-origin: center center;
fill:#fff;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" height="40px" width="40px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 291.319 291.319" style="enable-background:new 0 0 291.319 291.319;" xml:space="preserve">
           
                <path style="fill:#3B5998;" d="M145.659,0c80.45,0,145.66,65.219,145.66,145.66c0,80.45-65.21,145.659-145.66,145.659
          S0,226.109,0,145.66C0,65.219,65.21,0,145.659,0z" />
      
    <path class="facebook"  transform="scale(0.8)" d="M163.394,100.277h18.772v-27.73h-22.067v0.1c-26.738,0.947-32.218,15.977-32.701,31.763h-0.055
          v13.847h-18.207v27.156h18.207v72.793h27.439v-72.793h22.477l4.342-27.156h-26.81v-8.366
          C154.791,104.556,158.341,100.277,163.394,100.277z" >
      <!--  анимация увеличения символа `F` при наведении  -->
    <animateTransform id="an_scale"
       attributeName="transform"
    type="scale"
    begin="indefinite"
    dur="0.4s"
    values="0.8;1.5"
    fill="freeze"/> 
           <!--  анимация уменьшенич символа `F` при уходе курсора -->    
        <animateTransform id="an_reduce"
      attributeName="transform"
      type="scale"
      begin="indefinite"
      dur="0.4s"
      values="1.5;0.8"
      fill="freeze"/> 
    </path>  
            
        </svg>
```